# Modal text return undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

So, I've been researching this for quite some time. I have a modal with a textarea inside of it. What I want to happen is, when someone click Post i'd like to see what they post. At the moment, it's returning undefined and I cant understand why. Here is the code:

**test.component.html**

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Confess.</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="button" (click)="submitPost()" class="btn btn-primary postMssg">
    Post
  </button>
</form>    
<div *ngFor="let data of datasource; let i = index">
  {{ data.post }}
  <button
    type="submit"
    data-toggle="modal"
    [attr.data-target]="'#' + data.key"
    (click)="check('#' + data.key)"
  >
    Reply
  </button>
  <div
    class="modal fade"
    [attr.id]="data.key"
    tabindex="-1"
    role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true"
  >
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="close"
            data-dismiss="modal"
            aria-label="Close"
          >
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="commentText">Example textarea</label>
              <textarea
                class="form-control data.key"
                id="commentText"
                rows="3"
              ></textarea>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
            Close
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            (click)="addComment(data.key)"
            class="btn btn-primary"
          >
            Post
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**test.component.ts**

```
 addComment(key) {
    let res = "." + key;
    let complete = $("." + key).val();
    console.log(complete);
  }    
  check(key) {
    console.log(key);
  }


submitPost() {
    // console.log(this.idCount);
    let post = $("#textarea").val();

    if (post !== "") {
      // this.posts = [];
      let item = this.db.list("/test").push({
        post: post,
        name: localStorage.getItem("name"),
        likes: 0,
        id: this.idCount + 1,
        likeBtn: 0,
        fireBtn: 0,
        time: moment().format("llll")
      });

      this.db.database
        .ref("/test")
        .child(item.key)
        .update({ key: item.key });

      this.datasource.push({
        post: post,
        name: localStorage.getItem("name")
      });
    }

    let result = this.db
      .list("/testID")
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe(val => {
        val.forEach((value: any) => {
          this.db.database
            .ref("/testID")
            .child("1")
            .child("idCount")
            .transaction(count => {
              return count + 1;
            });

          this.unsubscribe(result);
        });
      });

    $("#textarea").val("");
  }
```

Please feel free to direct me to a post or article that may can help if you aren't willing to give your 2 cents. I've read plenty SO posts and nothing is quite like what I'm dealing with. I've done this before awhile ago and I don't remember having such a hard time putting it together. Anywho, i'm trying to make a comment section for posts for a website I created. Kind of hard to create a comment section when you can't see the data.

I figured it was a problem with my classnames but they all are unique and is populating when I tried console.logging them in the addComment section

Comment: Post the all related (Ts file all) code!

Comment: this is all of the code. Except a function called submitPost() that has nothing to do with this.

Comment: submitPost is function getting call when I click on post button

Comment: Feel free tp provide [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/rkdpkapjkrv?file=app%2Fform-field-overview-example.html)

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I just included the submitPost function

Comment: Thanks but unable to open a dialog due to which asking for stackblitz of current working code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The textArea has not assigned a model. Use a ngModel in textarea and pass that model to the tag where you close the modal.

ADD:

```
  <ion-textarea placeholder="Comienza a dictar" [(ngModel)]="data" name="title" class = "botonesNotaPorAudio"></ion-textarea>
```

`data` contains the value of your textArea, 
that is, if you write "Hello", THE VALUE OF TEH VARIBLE  is "Hello".

In the ".ts" file you can do somthenig like this:

```
dismiss(data:any) {  
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(data);
  }
```

And u will recibe the information in your compenent with

```
 modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
  this.otherPuntoDescripcion=Object.assign({},data);
  this.puntoDescripcion.getDescripcion(this._dataBaseService,this.selectConvocatoria,localStorage.getItem("idPunto")).then(
    (resp:any)=>{   
      this.listPuntoDescription=resp;
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: example please? I've never used ngModel before